# Hibernate SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I can not understand why hibernate can not execute this query on Oracle 12c database .

```
SELECT *
FROM T_MESSAGE m
         inner join T_METADATA smj on smj.C_ID = m.F_SYSTEM_METADATA_JSON
         inner join T_MESSAGETHREAD mt on mt.C_ID = m.F_MESSAGE_THREAD
         inner join T_EXCLUDEDUSER exu on exu.F_MESSAGE_ID = m.C_ID
WHERE m.c_deleted = 0
  AND mt.C_ID > 121
  AND exu.F_USER_ID <> 293;
```

**NOTE** : I replaced `?` to correct values .
**NOTE** : I used native sql query .

I receive this exception on Hibernate :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

What is wrong ?
How can fix this problem ?

Comment: Remove the `;` from your SQL String

Comment: haha , Thank you man :D